# Rigify Deform Bones are Squashing

Tags: bones, rigify, inverse-kinematics

I recently started using Rigify and I encountered an issue where moving the IK bones on a custom generated rig causes the deform bones (and by extension the mesh) to squash unevenly ever so slightly. I'd prefer the bones and mesh to stay the same length and size no matter what position the IK target is at.

I am using Blender 3.1.0.

I have linked a Blend file where I recreated the issue, as well as a gif displaying it more clearly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Link to .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LCBzf5Vl1cdkzntcWEk8EOmHcVzidvRo)

[image]

Comment: It's stretching because IK stretch is enabled (and because of some stretch-to bones.)  Select MCH-arm_2_ik and look on bone constraints.  Disable "stretch" for both IK constraints.

Comment: @Nathan That worked, thank you very much!